# Map exported to PDF background color is black ol5

Tags: openlayers

When I am exporting map to PDF, it is all looking black in backgroud.

Here is my code

```
map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {
    $('.filter').css('display','none');

    var canvas = event.context.canvas;
    event.context.fillStyle = "white";
    canvas.lineWidth = 2;
    canvas.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
    //showText(event.context,'left-top',dist,tahsil,village);
    //drawLegend(event.context,'right-bottom');
    drawNorthArrow(event.context,'right-top');
      WriteScaletoCanvas(event);

    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',1.0);
    var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);

    pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
    pdf.save(pdf_name);
    document.title=pdf_name;
    window.print(); 
    $('.filter').css('display','block');

    map.setSize(size);
  // map.getView().fit(extent, size);  //edit2: not needed
    mapView.setZoom(currZoom);  // edit2: set original zoom
    exportElement.disabled = false;
    document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
});
```

Here is the image

[image]

i need to have white color in background.

by applying this code

```
 event.context.fillStyle = 'white';
    event.context.fillRect(0, 0, event.context.canvas.width, event.context.canvas.height);
```

result is 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `precompose` before the `rendercomplete` to set a white background would avoid any transparent canvas which might be causing the problem.

```
map.on('precompose', function(event) {
    event.context.fillStyle = 'white';
    event.context.fillRect(0, 0, event.context.canvas.width, event.context.canvas.height);
});
```

Comment: no its not working.showing only white background not map..

Comment: updated the question please go through it.

Comment: Where are you adding it?  Take a look at the OpenLayers example with the OSM layer removed so there is only a vector layer, the pdf has a black background https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-9j2ee   But add the precompose and the pdf has a white background https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-u081y

Comment: yes now its working.

Comment: me too getting same map with black background. When I add this answer before 'rendercomplete', I'm getting error 'Uncaught TypeError: e.context is undefined'

Comment: @user123 Are you using OpenLayers 5?

Comment: no Openlayer 6.4.3

Comment: In OL6 each layer can have its own canvas so use `layer.on('prerender,', ...)` for your base layer if its is a vector layer.

Comment: It worked..Thanks alot @Mike